# DRY variable setting across templates (macro for variable?)

Tags: templating, macro, dry

I have a need for something like the following:

```
{# Template A #}
    {# Do X that sets variable x #}
    {# Do Y that sets variable y #}
    {# Pass x and y into A include partials #}

{# Template B #}
    {# Do X that sets variable x #}
    {# Do Y that sets variable y #}
    {# Pass x and y into B include partials #}
```

The logic for X and Y is the same in templates A and B.

Is there a way to write each once in some kind of dedicated partial and place them in templates A and B, something akin to `return` in a JavaScript function?

I'm not sure there is. I *think* that macros only produce front-end output. And so I have to duplicate the logic in each template. Is that right?

Comment: How good are your PHP skills?

Comment: Hi Lindsey. Not great. Is this plugin territory?

Comment: Not necessarily, though it would be a reasonable solution.  You can probably pull this off in raw Twig as well.

Comment: Ok. Am I right that you can’t use a Macro to change the state/contents of a variable – e.g. a hash – because a Macro is predicated on generating _markup_? If yes, is there another technique?

Comment: Have just found Robin Schambach’s 2017 answer to [Use a Twig macro to set a variable](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/23194/3507). I note that [Twig perversion](https://plugins.craftcms.com/twig-perversion) provides a `return` scope, which I think is what I need, but I’m nervous about relying on a third party plugin for this. Would be great if it were native to Craft.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in your comment, the [Twig Perversion](https://plugins.craftcms.com/twig-perversion) plugin will do exactly what you need. It allows you to `return` a value from a macro, which isn't typically something that Twig permits.

Personally, I'd consider it to be fairly safe to rely on this plugin for a few reasons. Marion is a long-standing and trusted developer in the community, the plugin is relatively simple, and could easily be replaced with a small custom module if it ever went defunct. It also doesn't touch your data, so removing it in the future won't cause any problems.

Comment: Twig Perversion relies on twig not changing drastically, which is a reasonably safe assumption.